# Retrieving fieldname of vectorlayer's unique id using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, unique-id

The name of vectorlayer's unique-id fieldname can be technically any string ("ID","FID","OID","id_0", etc) and its position can be technically anywhere. So `featureobject.fields().names()[0]` is not 100% reliable.

How do I retrieve it via PyQGIS?

In the GUI it is shown in the 'Information' tab of the Layer Properties dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested fully, but maybe this:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
pk_idx = lyr.primaryKeyAttributes()[0]
pk_name = lyr.fields()[pk_idx].name()

print(pk_name)
```

Comment: Thanks! The primaryKeyAttributes() returns a list. That implies there's also the possibility of using composite primary keys but I have never seen that in the orbit of QGIS. Interesting.